# Python 3 TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple

Tags: python

I want to have a a villager be assigned a random name out of 4 choices as well as a random response out of 4 choices but I keep getting "TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple" when i want to print the final name and response

```
def villager():
  responses = ("Hi", "Are you a hero?", "Are you from this village?", "There has been a dark shadow cast across the village")
  npcnamechoice = ("Talion", "Ratbag", "Mildreth", "Susan")
  random.choice(npcnamechoice)
  npcname = npcnamechoice + ": "
  print(npcname + "Hello my name is " + npcname + "would you like to talk")
  random.choice(responses)
  print("Press y to talk to the villager")
  if input() == "y":
    print(npcname + responses)
  else:
    print(npcname + "Goodbye")
```

Comment: The problem is that you can only concatenate tuple (not “str”) to tuple.

Comment: Like the error says... `npcnamechoice + ": "`, you can't add a string to a tuple

Comment: As explained already, here is an example of what is happening. Try it out yourself: https://pastebin.com/U8XZfnSf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't actually capture the random value. This on its own, just calls the function, it didn't reassign `npcnamechoice`

```
random.choice(npcnamechoice)
```

So, make another variable, or inline it

```
 npcname = random.choice(npcnamechoice) + ": "
```

Do the same for the responses

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you probably want to pick a random name. In that case, you should do

```
import random

def villager():
  responses = ("Hi", "Are you a hero?", "Are you from this village?", "There has been a dark shadow cast across the village")
  npcnamechoice = ("Talion", "Ratbag", "Mildreth", "Susan")
  npcname = random.choice(npcnamechoice) + ": "
  print(npcname + "Hello my name is " + npcname + "would you like to talk")
  random.choice(responses)
  print("Press y to talk to the villager")
  if input() == "y":
    print(npcname + responses)
  else:
    print(npcname + "Goodbye")
```

to assign a random name to the villager. I changed it in your code so that you could copy & paste it.